# How to add class to words starting with a hashtag in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

So let's say I have a string in jQuery that looks like

```
    result.text = "I tweeted something #one #two #three";
```

Is there a way to wrap all the words starting with a hashtag with a span class called "tweet-hash" ?

Comment: Yes, did you get stuck somewhere trying to do it?

Comment: There probably are duplicates of this question in SO already. Did you search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to use some Regex to find the symbol/word combination, and replace it and wrap it with a style tag and a CSS class.  CSS unfortunately doesn't have a selector for values like that.

```
$("#phrase").html($("#phrase").html().replace(/#([^ ]+)/, "<span class='hashtag'>$1</span>")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the example above will only replace the first hashtag it finds. If you add a `g` global to the regex expression, it will target all instances that match the expression:

```
$("#phrase").html($("#phrase").html().replace(/#([^ ]+)/g, "<span class='hashtag'>$1</span>");
```

I've thrown up an example on jsFiddle so you can see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/c26r9/