# How set style to a word that beings with letter #?

Tags: javascript, css, hashtag

I am creating a tag system in my website, I want to attach CSS to words that start with letter hash (#). Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: give this a go.
worked for me sometime ago..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048986/how-to-add-class-to-words-starting-with-a-hashtag-in-jquery

Comment: Have you tried the CSS attribute selector? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp

Comment: In CSS there is no way. Css has no selectors to match elements contents.

Comment: @rnrneverdies you can use CSS to target elements (title, <p> etc.) that contain particular characters or words using [attribute~=value], though it would target the whole element not just the individual word,

Comment: @Lyall what?! as I said, you can't match elements based _on its contents_, the example you given matches an attribute, not the element content.

Comment: @rnrneverdies you are right sorry, from the page I found it looked to me like it was targeting the contents of the attribute rather than the names of the attributes - my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, This can be done by following way:

html:

```
<p>
  #Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae aliquam, aut quod provident in incidunt quisquam perferendis aperiam ullam #quos ab ad cumque, doloremque repellat reiciendis modi sit consequuntur aliquid!
</p>
```

JavaScript and jQuery:

```
"use strict";
var allNodes,body,currentElement,currentElementString,split,splitWord,splitWord,splitLetters,stringMatch,newTag,i;

allNodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (i=0;i< allNodes.length;i++) {
  currentElement = allNodes[i];
  currentElementString = currentElement.innerHTML;
  split =  currentElementString.split(' ');
  for (i=0;i< split.length;i++) {
    splitWord = split[i];
    splitLetters = splitWord.split("");
    stringMatch = splitWord.match(/#/g);
    if (stringMatch == "#") {
      newTag = "<a>"+splitWord+"</a>"; 
      currentElementString = currentElementString.replace(splitWord,newTag);
      currentElement.innerHTMl = currentElementString;
      $(currentElement).html(currentElementString); 
    } 
  }
}
```

and Some Css:

```
a {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only attach styles to DOMElements. Depending on your use case you will need to use javascript, php or another language to find words that start with a # and wrap them in a  element with a class.

```
`<span class="my_tag">#tag</span>`
```

You can then use that class to add styles to this tag.

Comment: That is pretty idea thanks, But this is not an answer. Let suppose I've article and you know articles can write by anyone. So if someone puts #twitter into article. I want to fetch # and rest of the word which is `twitter`. How can I do this? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the twitter-text library to parse the text and find hashtags:

see https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text

Comment: Using libraries stemming from big data practices is generally a good practice (how much time is deployed for developing reliable and effective algorithms is unbelievable), so I upped this answer.